# jQuery click fires twice but only registered once

Tags: jquery, click

I have an element click event that's firing twice on a single click, a common issue from searching, but I've ruled out may of the potential causes from other answers. The code is

```
console.log("registering label click");
$("label.tiletype").click(
  function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // stop the .tile click being called
    console.log("label clicked, x = " + event.pageX + ", y = " + event.pageY);
    // more code...
  }
}
```

When the page is loaded and the "label.tiletype" clicked, the log is

```
registering label click
label clicked, x = 679, y = 172
label clicked, x = 679, y = 172
```

Since "registering label click" only happens once, it can't be that the click is bound twice for any reason.

Since the pageX and pageY co-ordinates are the same, the double event occurs from the same physical click, not a second programatic click() being called on the element (I think, correct me if wrong).

The debug lines are only in this particular bit of code so there is no other click event firing.

I have checked the source in Firebug and there are multiple "label.tiletype" elements but none overlap on the screen, they are all display:block and float:left.

There is other stuff happening in the JavaScript file (line 375 https://github.com/okohll/agileBase/blob/200dd1c6c1a8968bc9d8f5b2b3d9188ac4776984/gtpb_clientside/resources/simple/simple.js) but whatever else is happening, the above statements must always be true logically.

This happens both in Firefox and Safari.

What have I missed?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okohll/cKgAp/

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/okohll/cKgAp/

Answer (score 4):

according to [this site](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/jquery-click-event-fires-twice/) a double use of `$(document).ready`could be the cause. try avoiding it by unbinding your function first:

```
$('label.tiletype').unbind('click').bind('click',
function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // stop the .tile click being called
  console.log('label clicked, x = ' + event.pageX + ', y = ' + event.pageY);
  // more code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that without success. If it was a double bind (no pun intended), then "registering click event" wouldn't log twice

Comment: what's very interesting: if i click the radio button in your fiddle exactly, i only get 1 alert, if i click the text, i get two. maybe this could lead to some solution.

Comment: Yes it did, I simultaneously found that the click on the input was bubbling through as a second event - see the answer I just added. Thanks.

Comment: I found that the unbind worked for me.  Whereas the stopPropagation() did not.  I also got two events in the fiddler using Chrome 26.0.1410.64

Answer (score 2):

Ah, found it! The label has an input wrapped inside and one of the events was due to a click on that propagating up.

Adding

```
$("label.tiletype input").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

to http://jsfiddle.net/okohll/cKgAp/

fixes it. Thanks for the prompt to do a jsfiddle, I initially thought I wouldn't be able to replicate it.

Comment: stopPropagation could break event delegation (your other code or other modules may not work). The better solution would be to fix the HTML structure, for example like this: http://jsfiddle.net/richard03/cKgAp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax error in it, it shall be

```
console.log("registering label click");
$("label.tiletype").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // stop the .tile click being called
    console.log("label clicked, x = " + event.pageX + ", y = " + event.pageY);
    // more code...
});
```

But this code works as expected (only one "label clicked" message is triggered). So you should probably check the rest of your code or HTML code validity (for example, unclosed label may cause this behavior).

Comment: Ah thanks, the missing ) was an error in my copying not the original code. I'll look for unclosed labels and other syntax errors though. I've just made a jsfiddle, I'll edit the question to add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("label.tiletype").on('click', function (event) {
   alert("label clicked, x = " + event.pageX + ", y = " + event.pageY);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cKgAp/6/