# What is causing .load() to fire twice here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read through some answers here. Have never had this issue before and can't seem to figure it out.Why is `.load()` function getting fired twice from one button click?

```
//proccess form
$('#special-offers-submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Click');
        send = true;
        $('#other-industry').val($('#industry').val());
        $('#popup-form input.input_field').each(function(){

                if($(this).val().length < 2)
                {
                    $(this).css('border-color','#cc0000');
                    $(this).siblings('label').css('color', '#cc0000');  
                    $('#errorMessage').show();
                    send = false;
                }
        });

        if(send)
        {
            data = $('#popup-form').serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $('#special-offers').load('http://www.avwebdesigns.com/ajax/popup-processor.php?'+data);    
        }
});
```

There is a button with the id `special-offers-submit`, once clicked I check all fields are filled out and attempt to submit the form via the `.load()` function - which also send an email. I am getting double emails and 'Click' is also being logged twice. If it makes a difference the container I am loading into is a fancybox.

Thanks for any help.

Bryan

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle I'm sure you'll find the issue in no time...

Comment: When is the JS executed? Is it in a js file or inline? What's around it, just DOM-ready or is it indented because it's within some other procedure? There's a simple way around it but it's better to find out why the event is being bound twice.

Comment: All the current browsers have JavaScript debugging. Set a breakpoint in the click handler and find out what's calling it via the stack trace

Comment: Use chrome dev' tool's network tab and look at the initiator column.

Comment: You are binding a click event on a submit button. Let the submit button do it's job. Bind a submit event on the form instead and `e.preventDefault()` would be able to prevent default form submission, something you cannot do with the click event on the button. See my answer below.

Comment: @user3558931 Don't want the button to do it's job before I make sure all fields have been filled out. Plus it's returning a message to a fancy box, not posting to another page. also, it's a button, not a submit, with type `button` so your probably right about `e.preventDefault()` not doing anything. I will include more complete code/fiddle tomorrow. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see more of your code but could you be attaching to the click event multiple times?

Try this:

```
$('#special-offers-submit').off('click').on('click', function(e){
```

Comment: But it's better to figure out why it's attaching more than once and fix that.

Comment: You have to figure out IF it's attaching more than once first :) There isn't enough information for me to debug his code

Comment: It definitely is attaching twice - we can see the code that creates the event and OP says it triggers twice.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I went with, posted a link to why it was firing twice in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('#special-offers-submit').click(` to:

```
$('#special-offers-submit').closest( 'form' ).submit(
```

Let the submit button do it's job - submit the form. Since you're using the click event `e.preventDefault()` does not prevent default form submission .... not even sure it really does anything. Therefore, the button click goes through without being prevented and the form submits as it is not prevented on button click event.

However, when you use the submit event on the form, then `e.preventDefault()` prevents default form submission.

Alternatively, you can use (**my best choice**):

```
$('#popup-form').submit(
```

Comment: I 100% agree with this sentiment - ALWAYS use the form submit, never a button. But this may not prevent the double triggering.

Comment: May be we should create a demo. What do you think?

Comment: With no further information from OP since asking questions over an hour ago, I don't think it's worth the effort when there are others who need help too.

Comment: Thanks guys, posted at work left before anyone responded. Will post more complete code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I found this happens if you have `$(document).ready` or `$(function{})` multiple times in the body of the code. The solution for me was

```
$('#special-offers-submit').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
 //rest of code the same in here
}
```

If anyone is curious, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724406/jquery-click-fires-twice-but-only-registered-once) is the link that helped me which includes a reference to someone else with a similar headache.

To be clear I should add I found this out to be the problem as nothing else on the page was using the same id, or trying to manipulate this element. The code also was fine when isolated, and works find on other sites.

Comment: This is exactly what @jnoreiga posted 15 hours before this answer, except he/she used the more up-to-date functions `.off()` and `.on()`. Neither answer gets to the bottom of the problem, it's just a band aid, which is why I didn't post the same answer in the first place.

Comment: @Popnoodles Did you actually read what I wrote instead of just looking at the code snippet - there is even a link.

Comment: The answer is no different. OP has been asked questions that will allow us to determine when it is being bound twice. I can't see that you've offered any new information.

Comment: @Popnoodles I am the op. The answer is different because it comes with a description and a link

Comment: Ok no problem Bryan, consider me out.